# How to compare last three data of MutableArray with String?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my application i have got data in Mutable array like this,

```
   MutableArray1:(
       "22.298166 , 73.165809",
       "22.300598 , 73.167183",
       "22.298101 , 73.166188",
       "22.298128 , 73.166194"
       "22.298130 , 73.166194"
      )
```

I want to compare a NSString with data **"22.298130 , 73.166194"** with last three data of MutableArray1.

Please suggest me how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if([Array1 count]>3)
        {
           for (int i = [Array1 count] - 4; i < [Array1 count]; i++) {
                if ([[Array1 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"22.298130 , 73.166194"]) {
                    NSLog (@"True");
                    //Write your Code Here
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = @[ @"22.298166 , 73.165809",
                    @"22.300598 , 73.167183",
                    @"22.298101 , 73.166188",
                    @"22.298128 , 73.166194",
                    @"22.298130 , 73.166194"];
```

If you just need to know, if it is inside the array:

```
NSString *searchString = @"22.298130 , 73.166194";    
BOOL found = [[array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange([array count]-3, 3)] containsObject:searchString];
NSLog(@"%@", (found) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

if you need to know the index, you can do

```
[[array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange([array count]-3, 3)] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString  *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isEqualToString:searchString]) {
        *stop = YES; //avoid further loops, if we had a positive hit.
         NSLog(@"%lu %lu", idx, [array count]-3+idx);  //index in subarray and in original array
    };
}];
```